# Basic question on countable intersection and union of sets

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am just a beginner at measure theory, and I have a very basic question on the following fact found in Robert Ash, Probability and Measure theory , page 7:

[image]

Now this strikes me as a little asymmetric.

Very informally speaking, and I know this makes no sense, but we seem to have to have a concept of "$b^-$" in that say $[a,b)=a...b^-$, a concept of {b} in $[a,b]=[a,b) \cup \{b\}$, but no corresponding concept of "$a..b^+$" which I would have defined exactly as per the first equation $\cap_1^{+\infty} [a,b+ {1\over n}) $

I ask because in David Williams "Probability with Martingales" 3.12, "Skorokhod representation of a random variable with prescribed distribution function", the distributions are perforce right-continuous - really, this is enforced (in my mind as it stands) by the 'asymmetry' above, as exhibited by the first equation.

Put in another way which might make more sense:

1. Is it possible to build a series of strictly decreasing sets $F_{n+1} \subset F_n$ such that the countable intersection $ \cap F_n=[a,b)$ ?
2. (And just to make sure): Does anything change is we allow uncountable intersections in (1) above ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Take $F_n=(a−1/n,b)$.
2. I may be very ignorant of this, but I think *uncountable intersection* is not a thing. I have only encountered finite or infinite intersection, which compile the arbitrary intersection. I don't think you can define $F_n$ if the intersection is uncountable, since the notation implies that it is countable.

Comment: for 1 ah yes that is true thank you! still I'm wondering why in the second equation highlighted it is not just as plausible to say $\cup_n (a,b-1/n] = (a,b]$ rather than (a,b)

Comment: @user3203476 It is because $(a, b-1/n]$ never includes the end point $b$. But $(a-1/n,b)$ always includes the end point $a$, intuitively speaking.

Comment: OK but then what is the difference between $\cup_n (a,b-1/n)$ and $\cup_n (a,b-1/n]$ ?

Comment: @user3203476 Could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: is it the case that $\cup_n(a,b−1/n)=\cup_n(a,b−1/n]=(a,b)$ ?

Comment: That is correct. Infinite union does not always preserve closed set. Loosely speaking, the closed part of $(a, b-1/n]$ is not preserve under infinite union.

Comment: I see . Thank you for your help !

Comment: You're most welcome. :)